# Decompiling a .NET 3.5 program to C#, issues with exporting

Tags: c#, .net, decompiling

There is a fairly old program I must modify to make some relatively minor changes - there are a few control variables like enum structs, magic strings and numbers from the ether that have worked fine for the last 4-5 years or so, but are now not good anymore. Naturally, however, in the ensuing years, the code has been lost so all we have is a decompilation option.

I have used both dotPeek and JustDecompile to get .csproj files out of the .dll files and the .exe file (there are 4 dlls and 1 exe altogether), but both solutions ended up with a near-endless stream of syntax errors and, in dotPeek's case, notations of issues like references to compiler variables.

I can obviously try to painstakingly work through each file and fix every syntax error as best I can, but it's looking like that could be as much as a week of effort.  I have never undertaken a decompile approach before, so when I realized the path I was looking at, I immediately wondered if I didn't know what I was doing.

Does this situation sound normal for a decompile project in .net?  Is there any way to more efficiently make a buildable project?  Am I using my tools wrong?  Is this a symptom of obfuscation (which I have no experience at all with)?

Thanks in advance, and please leave comments if more information is needed - since this is sort of out of my league I am not fully certain what is useful information and what is not.

Comment: You could try ILSpy, just to be sure :-)

Comment: Sure, I'll give it a go!  Certainly can't be any MORE broken! :p

Comment: Be sure to use the latest update of programs. There was bugs in early version of dotPeek and latest version (1.1.1.33) seems to work better for my projects.

Comment: I've seen those a lot - since .NET 3.0 (or 3.5, I can never remember which), when they started adding a lot of compiler tricks to C# like lambdas, auto-properties, and things like that, disassembled code can be very difficult to reassemble. One thing I'd suggest is to give .NET Reflector a try - they've been around the longest, so there's a good chance they've solved some or all of the issues. It's not free anymore, but it may be worth paying for it if it is able to solve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

I have used dotPeek, ILSpy and Reflector, all seem to do a great job at decompiling into C# code. I have only decompiled one entire project, this was with Reflector, and it required quite a bit of manual work to reassemble the project source code and to get it to work.

I doubt obfuscation is the problem you're facing; they either stop the above tools from decompiling, or they decompile just fine into the obfuscated (but working) versions of the code. In that case the code would not make alot of sense, for a human.

Sometimes these endless streams of syntax errors actually turn out to be a few missing references. I wouldn't know why compiler variables would appear in decompiled code as they should not appear in the executable.

Recently I had the same problem as you, and while using one of the tools to inspect the code, I used the Mono.Cecil library to *alter* the existing assembly. It's a bit hacky but saved some time in my case. I believe Mono.Cecil comes with the ILSpy package.

Comment: I'm in the middle of playing with ILSpy's decompilation right now but your solution is interesting.  Could I bother you to elaborate slightly on how the library is used?

Comment: Yeah, the ILSpy decompilation still had a ton of errors that would take forever to fix up.  Having investigated the Mono.Cecil library, it looks absolutely awesome, but is there a project out there that has a decent implementation of it out of the box?  If spending a week rectifying compilation errors sounded lame, spending a week making a project just to visualize the assembly I need to play with sounds just as lame.  I am not seeing a 'standard' implementation of it when googling or searching github.

Comment: This is their FAQ: http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil:FAQ - I'll post some code I used tomorrow.

Comment: @YYY See http://pastebin.com/j8hRW3Zx - I had to replace a string value being assigned to a property (I see I copy pasted the doccomments for the second method). Using IL instead of C# takes some getting used to.

Comment: Hilariously, Cecil actually throws an error upon attempting to open this DLL, claiming simply that it cannot be disassembled.  As I get further into this it's starting to become more obvious that a couple anonymous types being used as method return signatures is causing a ton of problems with decompilation.  It is a very non-standard thing so I'm not certain anything handles it right now.

Comment: I wouldn't spend more time on this approach then if I were in your shoes, hope you find a way to reach your goal.